# Invalid table alias or column reference b

Tags: sql, hive

What's wrong with this query (running in hive):

```
SELECT count(*) TotalCount, b.region_code
from XXX a
INNER JOIN YYY b
ON a.uid=b.uid
where a.dt = '2015-04-15'
group by b.region_code order by b.region_code
```

I think it should be pretty straightforward, but am getting this:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 6:32 Invalid table alias or column reference 'b': (possible column names are: _col0, _col1)
```

Here is the YYY table:

```
hive> desc YYY;
OK
status_code     int
uid    string
zip_code        string
keyword string
region_code     bigint
dt      timestamp
channel int
```

and XXX table:

```
hive> desc XXX;
OK
group_key     string
category    string
uid    string
dt      timestamp
```

Comment: The error is saying your `YYY` table does not contain the column `region_code`. It would help us more if you show us the table structure of your 2 tables.

Comment: added table structures

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
SELECT count(*) as TotalCount, b.region_code
from XXX a INNER JOIN
     YYY b
     ON a.ui = b.uid
where a.dt = '2015-04-15'
group by b.region_code
order by region_code
```

The problem with your code is that `b.region_code` doesn't exist after the `order by`.  The *alias* exists (`region_code`) because that is in the `select`.  The *qualified alias* does not, because the `b` is no longer valid after the `group by`.  I think you could write:

```
order by max(b.region_code)
```

But that would be silly in this case.

Note that this is common to all databases, except MySQL.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like no syntax errors when running it that way. I am trying to understand why b.region code doesn't exist after the group by, can you help explain that to me? What is alias vs. qualified alias?

Comment: @Daniel . . . A qualified alias means that the column has the table name preceding it -- this is a good habit, which you are generally doing.  You can think of the problem as being that the `order by` only knows about the expressions defined in the `select`.  `b.region_code` is an expression whose name is `region_code`.  This isn't 100% correct, but I think it helps with the intuition for the behavior you are seeing.