# group by date part of datetime and get number of records for each

Tags: hive

I have this so far:

```
select created_at,
DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(current_date()), TO_DATE(sales_flat_order.created_at)) as delay,
count(*) over() as NumberOfOrders 
FROM
magentodb.sales_flat_order 
WHERE
status IN ( 'packed' , 'cod_confirmed' )
GROUP BY TO_DATE(created_at)
```

But this is not working.

1. syntax error:

   Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10004]: Line 1:7 Invalid table alias or column reference 'created_at': (possible column names are: (tok_function to_date (tok_table_or_col created_at)))
2. `count(*) does not give sum for each grouped by date but instead all of the rows`.

Note : I am actually using hive but it is exactly like sql when it comes to queries

Comment: why you are using over() with count(*) ??

Comment: Should I not? Since we need to count rows that were grouped for a key, I thought it would work that way

Comment: i am not getting the purpose of over(); if you remove this your query wil work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select created_at,
DATEDIFF(TO_DATE(current_date()), TO_DATE(sales_flat_order.created_at)) as delay,
count(*) as NumberOfOrders 
FROM
magentodb.sales_flat_order 
WHERE
status IN ( 'packed' , 'cod_confirmed' )
GROUP BY Date(created_at)
```

Answer (score 0):

My phone won't allow me to post comments. But try this link it might guide you the right way.

[stackoverflow.com/questions/29704904/invalid-table-alias-or-column-reference-b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704904/invalid-table-alias-or-column-reference-b)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use date part(including year, month and day) of `created_at` for grouping.

```
select
date(created_at) as created_at_day,
datediff(curdate(), sales_flat_order.created_at) as delay,
count(*) as numberOfOrders
from magentodb.sales_flat_order
WHERE status IN ('packed', 'cod_confirmed' ) GROUP BY created_at_day
```

This query will show only the first order created on the day. Because you are grouping by the day. You can use `average` to find average delay of orders created for the day.